# How to create dynamic disks .qcow2 as it happens with VDI?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have created a virtual disk with QEMU / KVM in format .qcow2
[image]

I already know they are virtual [sparce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) disks, however, the problem is that when I try to copy & paste virtual disk (vol.qcow2) in another path (removable drive), it is still 20GB (not 3.32 MiB), something that does not happen with dynamic disks in Virtualbox.

I have tried editing the .xml file to put

```
sparce = true # supposedly this option is the one that defines if the disk is dynamic or fixed
```

But I have not been successful.

What should I do to create a virtual disk with QEMU / KVM / virt-manager in .qcow2 or RAW format and keep it similar size of virtualbox dynamic virtual disks (VDI nd other formats like a VHD, etc)?

PD: Please with QEMU/KVM virt-manager" in linux

thanks in advanced

Comment: You didn't mention "how" you back up. The following question outlines various options that retain the sparse-ness https://serverfault.com/questions/665335/what-is-fastest-way-to-copy-a-sparse-file-what-method-results-in-the-smallest-f

Comment: just copy&paste virtual disk (vol.qcow2) in another path (removable drive)

Comment: I just created a 100M sparse image in ~/ (193k on disk) and copied it over to /tmp - still 193k. Sparse support depends on the copy tools AND (more important) the target file systems. Since you said "removable drive" that isn't (by any chance) for matted vfs or such? Please try to copy in a console and use a different path on the same disk (to ensure your copy retains spares) and only then to the removable drive (if failing there mentioned the FS this is formatted).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert the existing disk in a new disk (that will use `preallocation=off`) with the following command:

`qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O qcow2 -o preallocation=off vol.qcow2 newdisk.qcow2`

where:

- the `-f` format flag specifies the format of the input disk
- the `-O` format flag specifies the format of the output disk
- the `-o` flag is used to specify some options for the output file, such as  the way data is allocated (in this case, no data preallocation)

Then use the new disk in place of the original disk:

- rename `vol.qcow2` as `vol.qcow2.bak` just to backup it. Delete it only when you are sure that `newdisk.qcow2` works as expected.
- rename `newdisk.qcow2` as `vol.qcow2`

If you want to create a dynamic virtual disk from scratch, you can run this command:

`qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=off <disk-name> <disk-size>`

where:

- `disk-name` is the name of the dynamic virtual disk
- `disk-size` is the maximum disk size (you can use k, M, G, T, P or E as suffixes)

Comment: Your answer is correct. I already tried it and it works (and I am grateful), but it only explains how to do it by command line and not by GUI with the "QEMU / KVM virtual machine manager" in linux

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to do it via GUI. That's the reason why I typically create the virtual disk by command line, and then, when creating a VM using virt-manager, I use the option to use an existing virtual disk.

Comment: ok. I will investigate this topic further to see if this is possible, although we agree, as in virtualbox, creating or resizing disks by command line is safer and better. thanks

Comment: When creating a new volume in the 'Add a Storage Volume' window (virt-manager 4.0) an option called 'Allocate entire volume now' that should do this can be found, but even if it's unchecked it doesn't work. It might be a bug in virt-manager that has not been addressed yet.